# Get the index of changed model in $watch - angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm watch a array of employees for any change using $watch("model"). I want to know the index of the element in the array which is being modified. How can I achieve this ?

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="employee.value" />
```

JS

```
$scope.employees = [
    {
      'value' : 'Tim'
    },
    {
      'value' : 'John'
    },
    {
      'value' : 'Bill'
    },
    {
      'value' : 'John'
    }
];



$scope.$watch("employees", function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue); //newValue shows all the 4 objects..
      //how to get the index of the changed object ?
},true);
```

Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/qj5zwIHVZXFLCRk9BG3U?p=preview

Comment: On what basis are you watching i do not see any input box in plunker from where value can be changed

Comment: you have to search for it manually, loop through employees and see if newValue and oldValue for particular index in array differ from each other

Comment: How are the values getting changed and plunker seems to be having some other program than yours.

Comment: Updated the plnk : http://plnkr.co/edit/qj5zwIHVZXFLCRk9BG3U?p=preview

Comment: @doodeec there can be 2 employees with same name, looping through the employees would result in incorrect updation.

Comment: @user1184100 I don't think so, it will always be correct because you will always compare the same index in `newValue` and `oldValue`

Comment: hmm yes got your point, will try that since there is no direct way of getting the changed object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to do the comparison manually.

Something like this:

```
var previous = [];

var updatePrevious = function(newPrevious) {
  angular.copy(newPrevious, previous);
};

updatePrevious($scope.employees);

$scope.$watch("employees", function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue !== oldValue) {
    for (var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {

      if (angular.equals(newValue[i], previous[i])) continue;

      var changedEmployee = newValue[i];
      console.log('Changed employee:', changedEmployee);

      var index = newValue.indexOf(changedEmployee);
      console.log('Index:', index);

      updatePrevious(newValue);
    }
  }
}, true);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/MF8ANC83yXaBYevUNzAm?p=preview