# $watch how to get the which value has been changed in the array?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I am new to `angularjs`. In this snippet I have an array which is like -

```
$scope.jsonData = [{
        annotationType: "Full Name:"
        endOffset: "17"
        startOffset: "0"
        type: "FullName"
        value: "A"
    },
    {
        annotationType: "Email:"
        endOffset: "188"
        startOffset: "133"
        type: "FullName"
        value: "B"
    }
]
```

Now, Here I am using a watch.

```
$scope.$watch('jsonData', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log("Value changed==>", newVal);
}, true);
```

Now with this, my jsonData may get updated frequently, It may get added an element or remove. So, I from this watch How will I get to know which element has been added or which has been deleted or which elements value has been updated? And also if new value is added then what is that value or index of that value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709260/get-the-index-of-changed-model-in-watch-angular

Comment: But here I will get to know which value has been updated , but if a value has been added then what is that value and index ? Thant How will I get to knwo ?

Comment: first of all, that's not a valid object inside of your `jsonData`

Comment: Please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: objects will only be removed or added in the array right ?

Comment: Right. for example,  {
        annotationType: "Telephone:"
        endOffset: "190"
        startOffset: "178"
        type: "tele"
        value: "B"
    }  So, Here it is added a new one. And If In the  example given in question fullName is there where value is one property that might get changed it may become C . So such type of things can happen.

Comment: is there any unique thing for different objects ? any property which would be unique for every object ?

Comment: Yes Annotation Type can be an unique Id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168851/discussion-between-george-bailey-and-ganesh-kaspate).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can do something like that :

```
newObjects = newVal.filter(new => !oldVal.some(new => JSON.stringify(new) == JSON.stringify(old)) )

removedObjects = oldVal.filter(old => !newVal.some(new => JSON.stringify(new) == JSON.stringify(old)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If `annotationType` is unique then this the way to get the added or removed elements in your `jsonData` array.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.jsonData = [{
        annotationType: "Full Name:",
        endOffset: "17",
        startOffset: "0",
        type: "FullName",
        value: "A"
    },
    {
        annotationType: "Email:",
        endOffset: "188",
        startOffset: "133",
        type: "FullName",
        value: "B"
    }
]
var i = 0;
$scope.addInArray = function(){
i++;
   $scope.jsonData.push({
        annotationType: "Yo:"+i,
        endOffset: "17",
        startOffset: "0",
        type: "Yo",
        value: "Yo"
    })
}

$scope.removeFromArray = function(){
  $scope.jsonData.pop()
}

$scope.$watch('jsonData', function(newVal, oldVal) {

      if(newVal.length > oldVal.length){
       var values = oldVal.map(e=>e.annotationType)
          //an object has been added
            var changed = newVal.filter(function(obj){
             return !(values.includes(obj.annotationType)); });
             console.log("Added object is ",changed[0])


      }
       if(newVal.length < oldVal.length){
       var values = newVal.map(e=>e.annotationType)
          //an object has been removed
            var changed = oldVal.filter(function(obj){
             return !(values.includes(obj.annotationType)); });
             console.log("removed object is ",changed[0])


      }
}, true);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<button ng-click="addInArray()">Add</button>
<button ng-click="removeFromArray()">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So, Here, first annotation type is full Name and this may get updated to the some another value but annotation Type will always be FullName.

Comment: I explicitly asked you about update and you clearly mentioned that items will only be updated or removed right  ?

Comment: Actually what I have to do is that I have an array and on that array itself on front end I am doing some changes and removing some things. So, For sending this array to backend I want to send an array which are the updated values only and the ones which are not updated.

Comment: Yes, But If you see my comment on that question It is like Right. for example, { annotationType: "Telephone:" endOffset: "190" startOffset: "178" type: "tele" value: "B" } So, Here it is added a new one. And If In the example given in question fullName is there where value is one property that might get changed it may become C . So such type of things can happen.

Comment: Hey George, Now here If FullName is deleted then It comes in that console, But If again the same thing is added as a FullName with the same value then Its like removing and adding the same thing again, so there While maintaining the updated values its also adding that values

Comment: I mean Finally what I want is that When I first gets an array then what is the difference between that array and newly created or deleted or updated array , so that I can send only the changed things , not the ones which were in the previous data as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you use $scope.$watch you're only verifying if the value changed(in case it's a primitive variable) or if the reference changed (in case the watched variable is a referece variable (like arrays and objects).

If you want to watch for changes in the array, use $watchCollection.
If you want to watch for changes in the elements of the array, use $watch passing the last parameter as 'true'.

**Note that it all affects the performance of the app. Being the watch by value the least performatic, and the watch by reference the most performatic.**

All this can be seen in the following image:

[image]